# PJSIP 2.4 video orientation change propagation

Tags: ios, pjsip

In my application I am running into issues handling a scenario where a capture device on one side of the conversation changes his orientation, which needs to reflect on the rendering device on the other side.

I am using iOS and have figured out how to use pjsua_vid_win_rotate() to deal with changes of orientation assuming the capture side of the conversation is using a static orientation. The issue seems to be that the render side of the conversation does not get notified that the orientation of the video being sent to him has changed. What is the proper way to handle this with pjsip?

So basically the problem is as follows:

1. User A is in portrait.
2. User B is also in portrait and sets window rotation to 270. This leads to a proper video render.
3. User A changes orientation to landscape mid call.
4. User B needs to change his window rotation to 0 to accommodate the change but is not aware a change has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an RTP extension that may be used to carry mobile orientation data. It isn't supported in PJSIP yet. [summary of existing standards for CVO](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/rtcweb/current/msg08977.html)

Or you may wish to use application specific RTCP APP type packets to transmit in a custom format (freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1889/33.htm)

Either one of these options will require changes to the way PJSIP listens to and creates RTP. This can be accomplished by creating a Media Transport Adapter: [PJSIP Media Transport Adapter](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Media_Transport_Adapter)